# Determine if UITableViewCell's position within screen

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, cell

I'm trying to determine the position of a UITableViewCell with respect to the screen. For example, imagine I have a table view with 13 cells (and only 6 of them are visible on the screen, to see the rest you would have to scroll) and I would like to programmatically determine which one of my 13 cells is the last visible one at any point in time.

I am trying to create an effect like this:

[image: TableView last cell]

And as you scroll down, only the last cell is "blurred" (until you reach the end of the cells).

What I would like to do looks something like this:

```
if table has more cells that aren't visible at the moment
  last visible cell has a different colour
otherwise all cells have the same colour
```

Now, I can see a very trivial solution being to add a semi-transparent PNG that will achieve this effect but I would like to know if it is possible to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UITableView` extends from `UIScrollView`, so you can get the `contentOffset` in order to know if it's at the end of its content using `yourTableView.contentOffset` and compare with `contentSize`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I used: `float bottomEdge = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height;` and then a check like this: `bottomEdge >= scrollView.contentSize.height`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way to get what you want, is creating a gradient in your UITableView

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
        gradient.frame = self.view.bounds;
        gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor clearColor]CGColor], (id)[[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor], nil];
        [self.view.layer addSublayer:gradient];
```

Don't forget to include Quartz in your project.